# Why is compiler not flagging this as an Error instead of warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{
public:
    test() { cout<<"CTOR"<<endl; }
    ~test() { cout<<"DTOR"<<endl; }
};

int main()
{
 test testObj();
 cout<<"HERE"<<endl;

}
```

Output:

```
HERE
```

Compiler skips the line "test testObj(); " and compiles the rest with warning and when run will generate the output. The warning is "prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?) in VC++ 2008. Why does it not throw an error?

Comment: ... because it's not an error. It's valid code.

Comment: Then why is that line not hit? May be i am confused ? whats supposed to happen in the above snippet?

Comment: @rocky: It's a declaration, not executable.  So what does it mean to be "hit"?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ok . How do i use or initialize this testObj variable?

Comment: @rocky: Your code doesn't have a variable.  That's your problem.

Comment: @rocky: In your code, `testObj` isn't a variable, it's a function. That is what the warning is telling you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's not an error.

Your code has fallen foul of the [*most-vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (in summary, `test testObj();` doesn't define a variable, it declares a function).

Comment: It's not really the vexing parse as described in the page that you've linked to. That would be `test testObj(test());`.

Comment: On the one had: What should it tell you? That your code is 100% correct? On the other hand: I'm pretty sure that Clang issues a warning in such a situation... (Clang >>> GCC)

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The OP's is just a simpler example, though, right?  The fundamental principle is that it's interpreted as a function declaration, not a variable definition.

Comment: Yes, it's simpler so not really as vexing. The _most vexing_ parse is usually one that needs disambiguating with extra parentheses around the initializer expression which is a bit different from the simple fix needed here.

Comment: @CharlesBailey:  I don't know, your example isn't nearly as vexing as my personal favorite, `std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>(cin), std::istream_iterator<int>());` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Simply, because it's not an error to declare a function such as the one you declared. The warning should be useful enough, though.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the () from the constructor call in Main

```
int main()
{
    test testObj;
    cout<<"HERE"<<endl;
}
```